# Does positioning of divs effect SEO?

Tags: html, search-engine, seo, google-search

On site I have div containers in this sequence:

1. Less important left side bar
2. Less important right side
3. At last the core center content

As the core content comes after side bars; does this have any bad impact on SEO. If yes than how can I bring center div before sidebars. **Need fluid center and fixed sidebars.**

```
    #left {float:left;width:200px;}
    #right {float:right;width:200px;}
    #center div {margin: 0 200px;}
    <!--X-->
    <div id="left"> ... </div>
    <div id="right"> ... </div>
    <div id="center"> ... </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Apart from the most commonly known things like keyword reach titles,
>   key-phrases density of the content, good meta tags etc. there is one
>   aspect less known: the fact that each part of the content is ranked
>   based on its relative position within the whole content of the page
>   and also on the degree of uniqueness among the content from all the
>   pages of the site. This comes from a simple, natural principle that,
>   if a page wants to “say” something, it will start with it and put the
>   rest of less important things after. So the most important part of the
>   content should be found at the beginning.But, if a portion of content
>   seems to appear on too many pages (like the headers, menus, sidebars
>   content etc.), then it gets to be considered “common” – which is the
>   opposite of special, unique -, hence less important from the content
>   point of view, bearing less “SEO juice” as it is called."

Searched a bit and found this [here](http://dionesku.com/better-seo-performance-through-css-content-positioning-46.html)

Answer (score 0):

Early in 2011 Google released a "layout" algorithm update which penalized pages for having div's that displayed advertising banners at the top of the page and before the unique content or text of the page.

If advertising is important and needs to remain top, above the fold and you wish to avoid this penalty, consider using position:relative to place your ad above the div's that precede it in the html ordering of the page code.

This way you you will have the best of both worlds, keeping the code examining algorithm happy and your site visitors will be helping to pay the way for your site, by clicking on ads at the top of the page. (sort of like they way Google arrange their search results ; )